# Service Fabric Actor partitioning

Tags: partitioning, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have a set of around 100 actors with Int64 Id's. All actors Id's at this stage are below 100, but over time this grow well beyond this.

When using the default partition configuration of Ranged Partitions using the entire Int64 range as keys, all the actors are lumped into the one partition.

I can see there is also a Named Partition strategy, but this requires each partition to defined at deploy time.

How can I evenly distribute my actors across all partitions without arbitrarily limiting the range?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out the answer to this is quite simple. Use a wellknown string pattern which includes the Int64 ActorId. For instance, $"ActorId_{Int64}".

Comment: Abit of clarification, maybe a small code sample showing how you set the actor id would be helpful to others. I am confused about, if the solution was to use a string actorid instead to distribute the hashing?